# Using MoM for data-transfer in distributed-systems?

Tags: rpc, data-transfer, distributed-system, mom

I'm new to distributed systems and try to get an fitting architecture and frameworks for my scenario.

I have an scenario, where many heterogeneous computers shall be connected as a distributed system. Some computers can mine data and store these locally, other want to access the data for visualization. The data must be transfered regularly and can be quite big (some MegaBytes), to create plots out of it. I also want to be able to start services (e.g. data visualization) on specific computers.

- Can I transfer the data with an MoM, like ActiveMQ, efficiently? For Example that my data visualization services subscribe the topic with the needed data and the data miner publishes it. Would be be fast enough for having live data updating 10 times per second?
- Would an RPC Framework be more efficient?
- Can i combine a overlaying MoM with an RPC Framework or a socket Connection for the data-transfer? Or does this make sense at all?